# How to troubleshoot DotNetNuke under construction page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

Hi have a few DotNetNuke websites that intermittently show the under construction page for no apparent reason. I just load and resave the web.config file and it restarts correctly for a few weeks.

I am looking to find ways to identify the source of the problem, I guess it has somehing to do with the database connection or user, but I really don't know where to start troubleshooting and what tools to use to find the issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to http://www.mydomain.com/install/install.aspx when you're getting the Under Construction message that will likely tell you that the site can't connect to the database server.

So from there, you will want to check what is going on with your connection to your database. One thing you might try to start, is change the User Account that you are using to connect to the database server. Maybe create a new SQL user/password and connect with that one, instead of the existing account.

I had a website that had this problem, with a remote SQL server, and unfortunately, come to think of it, I didn't do anything to fix it, eventually it just stopped doing that...

Comment: Thanks Chris, in fact anything I do that touches the web.config file or forces an app pool refresh fixes it and yes, it is related to the sql server connection. It is probably related to the sql server user account since I have many other DNN installs on the same server and when it happens, it usually affects only on site at a time. Maybe my question should have been: is there any sql server logs relating to a user not able to connect to a database...